How do i put a text above wrapper box?
I've followed a tutorial on YouTube how to make a simple login form but i want to add some things myself.
I want to add a "Welcome" text above the login form and tried using h1 but the text appear on the left of the box not above it. here's a picture of how i want it to make it easier to understand:

Here's my code:


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}


body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left,
    #d4d4d4,
    #dedede,
    #ececec,
    #f5f5f5);
}

.wrapper{
    width: 400px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    color: fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    align-items: center;
}

.wrapper form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.wrapper table {
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper td {
    padding: 5px;
}


.wrapper h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper .input-box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* .input-box input{
    width: 70%;
    height: 60%;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: auto black;
    border: 2px solid rgba (255,255,255,.2);
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 15px;
} */

.input-box i{
    /* position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%); */
    right: 2px;
    top: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper .btn {
    width: 30%;
    height: 35px;
    background: #1570EF;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/login.css') }}">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="username">Username/ID</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" required></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-user me-2"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" required></td>
                    <td><i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>




Please add your code to the question. Without knowing what your current code is like, it's very hard to know how to help. That being said, if the h1 is appearing on the left of the box then it's probably centred using flex, so try adding the style flex-direction: column to the wrapping element.

oh yeah im so sorry i forgot, i already put it. thankyou

The reason is the .wrapper container is inside a flex container, the <body>. This is so it would be centered. But because it also centers on the horizontal axis, when you add an item before it you had them beside each other.
To remedy this, I add an element to wrap the h1 and the .wrapper so again there would be only one centered child to the <body>.


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #d4d4d4, #dedede, #ececec, #f5f5f5);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  color: fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper table {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.wrapper h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper .input-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0;
}


/* .input-box input{
    width: 70%;
    height: 60%;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: auto black;
    border: 2px solid rgba (255,255,255,.2);
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 15px;
} */

.input-box i {
  /* position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%); */
  right: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper .btn {
  width: 30%;
  height: 35px;
  background: #1570EF;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/login.css') }}">
  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper-wrapper">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <form action="">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="username">Username/ID</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" required></td>
            <td><i class="fas fa-user me-2"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" required></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




*To put text above a wrapper box in HTML, you can use the  element to create a container for both the text and the wrapper box. Here's an


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text Above Wrapper Box</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            text-align: center; /* Align the text in the center */
        }

        .text-above {
            margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add space between text and wrapper box */
        }

        .wrapper-box {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            margin: 0 auto; /* Center the wrapper box horizontally */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-above">Text Above Wrapper Box</p>
        <div class="wrapper-box"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



example:emphasized text*

OP is using flex as seen in the posted snippet and the other answer

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
